# Symfony 6: create Repository class for MappedSuperclass

Tags: symfony, doctrine, mappedsuperclass

I have a MappedSuperclass entity `Person`, and a number of child entities:

- Teacher
- Student
- Janitor

I want to implement a Repository class for all these entities with a method `findByString()` like this:

```
public function findByString($searchStr)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('C')
       ->where('C.name like :val')
       ->orWhere('C.surnames like :val')
       ->orWhere('C.dni like :val')
       ->setParameter('val', "%$searchStr%")
       ->orderBy('C.surnames', 'ASC')
       ->getQuery()
       ->getResult();
}
```

My first approach was to create a `PersonRepository` and then extend all the other repositories from this class, but something's wrong with the entity class in the repository.

When calling `$teacherRepository->findByString($search_str);` I get this error:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Repository\PersonRepository": argument "$className" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "string", you should configure its value explicitly.

```
<?php
namespace App\Repository;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;

use App\Entity\Person;

/**
 * @method Person|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Person|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Person[]    findAll()
 * @method Person[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class PersonRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry, string $className)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, $className);
    }

    public function findByString($searchStr)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('C')
           ->where('C.name like :val')
           ->orWhere('C.surnames like :val')
           ->orWhere('C.dni like :val')
           ->setParameter('val', "%$searchStr%")
           ->orderBy('C.surnames', 'ASC')
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult();
    }
```

And then, `TeacherRepository` like this:

```
class TeacherRepository extends PersonRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Teacher::class);
    }
}
```

**If I use the standard __contruct()** in PersonRepository with `Person::class` like this:

```
public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
{
    parent::__construct($registry, Person::class);
}
```

Then I get this error:

> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'person' doesn't exist

What is the correct approach in this case? or is it possible to create a Repository class for a MappedSuperClass and then have all child classes inherit its methods?

Comment: The problem is that autowire is picking up PersonRepository and trying to make it a service and then get's stuck on the string argument.  Make the repository abstract `abstract class PersonRepository` for autowire to skip it and then remove the constructor completely as it is not needed.

Comment: Perfect! That was the solution, thank you. Maybe if you want to write it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that autowire does not know that PersonRepository is just a base class and should not be a service.  Autowire gets confused by the string argument.

So make PersonRepository abstract and autowire will ignore it.  You can also remove the constructor as it does not do anything.

```
abstract class PersonRepository
{
    public function findByString($searchStr)
    {
```

Another approach would be to move the findBy stuff into a trait and eliminate the PersonRepository class completely.